# Oracle: Need help on a parent-child scenario

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help on the below scenario.

Table Structure:

### ACCT_XREF

```
CREATE TABLE ACCT_XREF
(
 ACCT_NO VARCHAR2(10),
 PRNT_ACCT_NO VARCHAR2(10),
 PRTY_ROWID VARCHAR2(10),
 ACCT_ROWID VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

### INPUT_ACCTROWID

```
CREATE TABLE INPUT_ACCTROWID
(
 ACCT_ROWID VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

### Sample Data:

```
INSERT INTO ACCT_XREF VALUES('1000',NULL,'100','1');
INSERT INTO ACCT_XREF VALUES('1001','1003','NULL','2');
INSERT INTO ACCT_XREF VALUES('1003',NULL,'102','3');

INSERT INTO INPUT_ACCTROWID VALUES('1');
INSERT INTO INPUT_ACCTROWID VALUES('2');
```

### ACCT_XREF

i/p data:

```
ACCT_NO    PRNT_ACCT_NO    PRTY_ROWID      ACCT_ROWID
-----------------------------------------------------
1000       NULL            100             1
1001       1003            NULL            2
1003       NULL            102             3
```

### INPUT_ACCTROWID

```
 ACCT_ROWID
 ----------
 1
 2
```

### EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
ACCT_NO   PRTY_ROWID
--------------------
1000      100
1001      102
```

The issue here is:

- ACCT_XREF is hierarchy based,
- So, When PRNT_ACCT_NO is NOT NULL,PRTY_ROWID will be NULL,
- In such cases, Pick the PRNT_ACCT_NO and    query the same table with
  ACCT_NO as a match conditon and fetch the    Party linked to that
  account i.e PRTY_ROWID

I have made an effort to achieve the same and below is my query:

```
SELECT ALL_INP.ACCT_NO,COALESCE(ALL_INP.PRTY_ROWID,C.PRTY_ROWID)
FROM
(
 SELECT A.*
 FROM
 ACCT_XREF A
 JOIN
 INPUT_ACCTROWID B 
 ON A.ACCT_ROWID=B.ACCT_ROWID
)ALL_INP
LEFT OUTER JOIN
ACCT_XREF C
ON ALL_INP.PRNT_ACCT_NO=C.ACCT_NO;
```

Not sure this is the best way, So wanted to know if there are better options.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you mean. You have recursive table which has primarily 2 types of data components. Either they are PARENT type (where PRNT_ACCT_NO is NULL) or CHILD type (where PRNT_ACCT_NO is NOT NULL). And if the CHILD is requested then it should navigate to parent first before fetching the data as output

Here is how to breakdown such a problem

1. Find out Father nodes and get the required data for CHILD nodes only
2. Find out Father nodes and get the required data for CHILD nodes only
3. Get node data for SOLO nodes (who are already PARENTS - no child)
4. Merge these 2 data sets
5. Bump it with final driving table INPUT_ACCTROWID for fetching required selective data only.

   ```
    SELECT XREF.ACCT_NO, XREF.PRTY_ROWID
       FROM    (SELECT CHILD.ACCT_NO AS ACCT_NO,
                       FATHER.PRTY_ROWID AS PRTY_ROWID,
                       CHILD.ACCT_ROWID AS ACCT_ROWID
                  FROM    ACCT_XREF FATHER
                       JOIN
                          ACCT_XREF CHILD
                       ON FATHER.ACCT_NO = CHILD.PRNT_ACCT_NO
                 WHERE CHILD.PRNT_ACCT_NO IS NOT NULL --**CHILD NODES ONLY**
                UNION ALL
                SELECT SOLO.ACCT_NO AS ACCT_NO,
                       SOLO.PRTY_ROWID AS PRTY_ROWID,
                       SOLO.ACCT_ROWID AS ACCT_ROWID
                  FROM ACCT_XREF SOLO
                 WHERE SOLO.PRNT_ACCT_NO IS NULL --**PARENT/SOLO NODES ONLY**
               ) XREF
            JOIN
               INPUT_ACCTROWID INPUT1 --**DRIVING TABLE JOIN**
            ON XREF.ACCT_ROWID = INPUT1.ACCT_ROWID
   ORDER BY 1 ASC
   ```

Here is the output

```
    ACCT_NO    PRTY_ROWID
    1000       100
    1001       102
```

Here is an explain plan for easier understanding of execution plan:

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 74  Bytes: 84  Cardinality: 3                          
    9 SORT ORDER BY  Cost: 74  Bytes: 84  Cardinality: 3                      
        8 HASH JOIN  Cost: 73  Bytes: 84  Cardinality: 3                  
            1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE CONTACTDBA.INPUT_ACCTROWID Cost: 18  Bytes: 14  Cardinality: 2              
            7 VIEW CONTACTDBA. Cost: 55  Bytes: 63  Cardinality: 3              
                6 UNION-ALL          
                    4 HASH JOIN  Cost: 37  Bytes: 35  Cardinality: 1      
                        2 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE CONTACTDBA.ACCT_XREF Cost: 18  Bytes: 21  Cardinality: 1  
                        3 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE CONTACTDBA.ACCT_XREF Cost: 18  Bytes: 42  Cardinality: 3  
                    5 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE CONTACTDBA.ACCT_XREF Cost: 18  Bytes: 56  Cardinality: 2
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this create a subquery in select, like the next query:

```
    select AX.ACCT_NO, AX.PRNT_ACCT_NO, AX.ACCT_ROWID,
           COALESCE(AX.PRTY_ROWID, (SELECT AX2.PRTY_ROWID 
                                    FROM ACCT_XREF AX2 
                                    WHERE AX2.ACCT_NO=AX.PRNT_ACCT_NO)
                   ) PRTY_ROWID
    from ACCT_XREF AX INNER JOIN INPUT_ACCTROWID IA ON (IA.ACCT_ROWID=AX.ACCT_ROWID)
```